# interactive theorem proving with no specified goal

Tags: coq

What's the best approach to do interactive theorem proving in Coq without specifying a `Theorem` definition first? I'd like to state some initial assumptions and definitions, and then interactively explore transformations to see if I can prove any interesting theorems without knowing them ahead of time. I'd like Coq to help me keep track of the transformed assumptions and check that my rewrites are valid, like when proving explicit theorems in interactive mode. Does Coq have support for this use case?

Comment: One thing I can think of is to start proving a goal of the form `H1 -> H2 -> ... -> exists P: Prop, P`. That is, "there is *some* provable proposition that follows from hypotheses H1, H2, ...". This allows you to play around with the hypotheses, and one you have discovered what you want the proposition `P` to be, you can instantiate it with the `exists` tactic.

Comment: Also possible to use the above approach and use `eexists` right off the bat (though that may introduce difficulties down the line).

Answer (score 0):

One convenient method is to use the `Variable`/`Hypothesis` commands (they do the same thing) to add assumptions and introduce example objects (eg, `Variable n:nat.` introduces a nat you can now work with). Then to get into theorem proving mode what I do occasionally is `Goal False.` to start proving `False`, just to make sure I don't accidentally prove the theorem. You can also `assert` and `admit` things to get additional assumptions without restarting the proof.

Comment: `Variable` and `Hypothesis` are just aliases for `Axiom`, right? One of the drawbacks of using that is that they don't show up above the horizontal line in interactive mode. I can make `n1 : nat` appear below the line with `Variable n : nat. remember n as n1`, but it also adds `Heqn1: n1 = n`, which might get annoying when I add more variables.

Comment: If you first open a section, then the variables and hypotheses will appear on top of the horizontal line during interactive proofs.

Comment: Yes - more specifically, Variable/Hypothesis are synonyms for `Local Axiom` when not in any section. `Parameter` and `Conjecture` are actually synonyms for `Axiom`.